# How to extract words from a list of the data frame list MESH from PubMed in R

Tags: r, mesh, stringr, text-extraction

I've been trying to extract data from a data frame that has a nested list, but  after trying to use string function (str_detect) I can only work on the variable Abstract here is a sample of my data

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(RISmed)
library(reticulate)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
RCT_topic <- 'Randomized Clinical Trial'
RCT_query <- EUtilsSummary(RCT_topic, mindate=2005, maxdate=2015, retmax=2000)
summary(RCT_query)
RCT_records <- EUtilsGet(RCT_query)
RCT_data <- data_frame('PMID'=PMID(RCT_records),
                       'Title'=ArticleTitle(RCT_records),
                       'Abstract'=AbstractText(RCT_records),
                       'Year Published'=YearPubmed(RCT_records),
                       'Month Published'=MonthPubmed(RCT_records),
                       'Country'= Country(RCT_records),
                       'Grant' =GrantID(RCT_records),
                       'Acronym' =Acronym(RCT_records),
                       'Agency' =Agency(RCT_records),
                       'Mesh'=Mesh(RCT_records))
#Latino
RCT_data$Latino <- grepl("Latino|latino|Hispanic|hispanic",RCT_data$Abstract)
table(RCT_data$Latino)
RCT_true = RCT_data[RCT_data$Latino == "TRUE",]
RCT_true %>% str_detect("Hispanic Americans")
RCT_true %>% mutate(Latino_Mesh = ifelse(Mesh %>% str_detect("Latino|latino|Hispanic|hispanic"), "yes", "no"))
```

This code will have created a sub of 11 observations that R has read have the word for latino or hispanic in the variable Abstract, I'm trying to find out a way to have R read the variable Mesh but it doesn't seem to be able to read the whole nested list even when you see each variable you can clearly see that the word Hispanic American is there in the list

```
{r}
RCT_true$Mesh
```

I'm trying to find a way to so that R can read RCT_true$Mesh and return that Yes there is a word "Hispanic Americans" in it in a new column like I did before with the Abstract variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since RCT_true$Mesh are lists containing a data frame, each data frame should be evaluated with `grepl` function and save results in an indexer vector (i.e. `RCT_true$Mesh_Latino`):

```
lapply(RCT_true$Mesh, function(x){

   any( grepl("(Latino|latino|Hispanic|hispanic)", as.character(x$Heading) ) )

  }) %>% 
  unlist() %>%
  as.logical() -> RCT_true$Mesh_Latino

RCT_true[RCT_true$Mesh_Latino == "TRUE",]

# # A tibble: 5 x 12
#  PMID  Title Abstract `Year Published` `Month Publishe… Country Grant Acronym Agency Mesh  Latino Mesh_Latino
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>               <dbl>            <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <lis> <lgl>  <lgl>      
#1 2671… Beyo… "Within…             2015               12 United… CA01… CA      NCI N… <dat… TRUE   TRUE       
#2 2670… Trea… OBJECTI…             2015               12 United… KL2 … TR      NCATS… <dat… TRUE   TRUE       
#3 2669… Vali… "Resear…             2015               12 England NA    NA      NA     <dat… TRUE   TRUE       
#4 2668… The … BACKGRO…             2015               12 United… K23 … MH      NIMH … <dat… TRUE   TRUE       
#5 2665… Heal… BACKGRO…             2015               12 United… R01 … HL      NHLBI… <dat… TRUE   TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to work on a work around for this for some time, but a quick learning question on how 'as.logical() -> RCT_true$Mesh_Latino'  is different from inverting and using 'RCT_true$Mesh_Latino = as.logical()' because I've not seen before the use of ->

Comment: When I try to use the whole code RCT_data

 'lapply(RCT_data$Mesh, function(x){

   any( grepl("(Latino|latino|Hispanic|hispanic)", as.character(x$Heading) ) )

  }) %>% 
  unlist() %>%
  as.logical() -> RCT_data$Mesh_Latino

RCT_data[RCT_data$Mesh_Latino == "TRUE",]'

 I get the following error  _Error in x$Heading : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors_

Comment: It is due to that columns does not exist, but that's what I get when I followed you code. The idea behind above answer is mainly process each list and apply `grepl` function where it better fits. On above case, column `Heading` were suitable

Comment: So what column would I have to create?  I've tried various work arounds and  well yes it works perfectly for the example above, but if I were to do this on RCT_data would I have to change something specifically? I've worked recreating a new RCT_data$Latino and using the str_detect and mutate portions but to no avail

Comment: well, you can change `as.character(x$Heading)` by `as.character( x[[1]] )`